Actualización de datos en MYSQL desde PHP
No soy muy bueno programando, recién empiezo en este mundo y me he encontrado un problema que no se como abordar.
Tengo un script de php que sirve para guardar en una BBDD de MYSQL todas las ciudades que existen dentro de una isla. Es un bucle que recorre todas las islas y guarda la informacion.
(Es una especie de minijuego lo que estoy haciendo)
Las ciudades pueden aparecer o desaparecer, entonces el script se ejecuta de forma diaria para actualizar la informacion.
Para controlar si una ciudad existe o ha dejado de existir al principio de mi codigo pongo esto:
// Establecer inicialmente todas las filas a 'no' en la columna 'existe'
$sqlInicializar = "UPDATE monitorizar SET existe = 'no'";

Luego mas adelante del código tengo un bucle que recorre todas las islas y actualiza la información de la BBDD. Si la ciudad existe se cambia el valor de la columna existe a si.
$sql = "INSERT INTO monitorizar (jugador, alianza, coordenadas, nombreciudad, nivelciudad, maravilla, recursolujo, idjugador, fecha, state, resourceLevel, tradegoodLevel, idcity, existe) 
        VALUES ('$jugador', '$alianza', '$coordenadas', '$nombreciudad', '$nivelciudad', '$maravilla', '$material', '$idjugador', '$fecha', '$state', '$resourceLevel', '$tradegoodLevel', '$id', 'si')
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        jugador = VALUES(jugador), alianza = VALUES(alianza), coordenadas = VALUES(coordenadas), nombreciudad = VALUES(nombreciudad),
        nivelciudad = VALUES(nivelciudad), maravilla = VALUES(maravilla), recursolujo = VALUES(recursolujo), idjugador = VALUES(idjugador),
        fecha = VALUES(fecha), state = VALUES(state), resourceLevel = VALUES(resourceLevel), tradegoodLevel = VALUES(tradegoodLevel), idcity = VALUES(idcity), existe = 'si'";

Lo que consigue con la columna "existe" es mantener un control de las islas. Si una ciudad no existe al final del código la borro de mi BBDD.
$sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM monitorizar WHERE existe = 'no'";

El problema que estoy teniendo es a la hora de mostrar un mensaje en pantalla por cada ciudad que se borra.
Antes de borrar las ciudades que no existen ejecuto esto:
// Obtener las ciudades marcadas como "no existe"
$ciudadesNoExistentesQuery = "SELECT idcity, nombreciudad, coordenadas FROM monitorizar WHERE existe = 'no'";
$ciudadesNoExistentesResult = mysqli_query($conexion, $ciudadesNoExistentesQuery);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ciudadesNoExistentesResult)) {
    $idcity = $row['idcity'];
    $nombreciudad = $row['nombreciudad'];
    $coordenadas = $row['coordenadas'];

    // Enviar mensaje de Telegram para esta ciudad
    echo "La ciudad se ha borrado";      

}
Lo que ocurre es que me muestra el mensaje para todas las ciudades. Es como si la query que actualiza la información de si existe o no existe no guardara los datos en la BBDD hasta que el script finalice. Como al principio del todo pongo que ninguna ciudad existe me muestra el mensaje para todas las ciudades.
No se como puedo forzar a que antes de que se ejecute el codigo que me muestra el mensaje me asegure que los datos se han actualizado bien en la BBDD.
He probado a poner mysqli_autocommit($conexion, true); al principio de mi codigo pero no hace nada.
Muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda.

Entiendo que después de cada SQL estás ejecutando el correspondiente mysqli_query, verdad?

Si. Despues de cada SQL tengo puesto esto.             if (!mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)) {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conexion);
mysqli_rollback($conexion);
exit;
}

Saludos Acorde a lo que expones te comento; primero ejecuta el SELECT y su resultado guardalo  (en un array o string) para al final mostrarlo (concluido el DELETE). Es lo básico si todo pasa (no hay error intermedio).

¿Cuál es la clave primaria de tu tabla? ¿Es idcity?

Yo veo desde el principio un problema serio de enfoque cuando leo esto: Para controlar si una ciudad existe o ha dejado de existir al principio de mi codigo pongo esto:  UPDATE .... ¿Por qué hay que estar actualizando una tabla cada vez que un código inicia? Cuando hablamos de bases de datos hablamos de persistencia de los datos. Por tanto, si una ciudad existe o no, debe quedar reflejado en una tabla que indique eso. Luego, tú puedes verificar la existencia de dicha ciudad mediante un SELECT COUNT(*) FROM laTablaRelacionada WHERE laCiudad=elIdDeLaCiudad  al iniciar la aplicación ...

... Pero ¿por qué un SELECT y no un UPDATE? Porque un UPDATE podría significar modificación no solamente de una tabla, sino también de los índices que intervienen en esa tabla y sus tablas relacionadas, entre otras cosas. El error de enfoque se refleja también cuando dices esto: Las ciudades pueden aparecer o desaparecer, entonces el script se ejecuta de forma diaria para actualizar la informacion. Pues bien, en un modelo de datos bien diseñado, esas ciudades que aparecen o desparacen se pueden controlar con restricciones de integridad referencial. ...

... Lo cual implica que no hay necesidad de monitorear desde un script lo que ha ocurrido en los datos, porque el SGBD es capaz de todo eso por sí sólo. El problema principal en lo que nos planteas es pensar la base de datos como un almacén de datos sin vida, al que hay que hacerle todo por programación y no, una base de datos es realmente un SGBD, Sistema Gestor de Bases de Datos. Es decir, un sistema capaz de gestionar cualquier cosa de esos datos. O sea, que si una ciudad desaparece el sistema borra esa ciudad de la tabla relacionada, y si una ciudad reaparece ...

... el sistema inserta esa ciudad en la tabla relacionada, sin necesidad ninguna de que el usuario intervenga mediante código o de un script que se lance cada X tiempo. Es  más, en caso de necesitar un código que se lance cada X tiempo, el SGBD también dispone de eventos para ello. En conclusión, el problema principal en la pregunta que planteas es que estás tratando a la base de datos como un almacén de datos muerto, al que debes reanimarlo mediante tu propio código y NO, una base de datos no es eso.
